# Navigation menu on episerver cms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, episerver

I am new to episerver CMS. I have installed episerver cms alloy sample site. Also I found the code to show the navigation menu on the "_Root.cshtml".

```
   @Html.RenderEPiServerQuickNavigator()
```

So I have used same code on my new website to render the navigation menu

```
 <nav id="topnavigation">         
        @Html.RenderEPiServerQuickNavigator()       
    </nav>
```

The Navigation is not showing on my website. Can any one help me to implement navigation menu on my episerver cms website?

Comment: The menu is only rendered if you're logged in as an editor. Are you logged in?

Answer (score 2):

`RenderEPiServerQuickNavigator` will only render the menu available for logged in editors

[image]

[image]